# How to get the IP address of the server on which my C# application is running on?

Tags: c#, ip-address

I am running a server, and I want to display my own IP address.

What is the syntax for getting the computer's own (if possible, external) IP address?

Someone wrote the following code.

```
IPHostEntry host;
string localIP = "?";
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
    {
        localIP = ip.ToString();
    }
}
return localIP;
```

However, I generally distrust the author, and I don't understand this code. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Regarding the external IP address, I don't think there is a local approach for retrieving that. The localhost may be behind a NAT router that is translating local network addresses to public ones. Is there a (local) way to verify if that's the case? I don't know of any...

Comment: The sample uses the DNS to get IP-address, I have had experience with DNS having wrong information. For that case the sample could respond with _wrong_ information.

Comment: @leiflundgren I have also had experience with DNS having wrong information. My answer describes how I obtained the IP address that I needed without relying on DNS when I faced that situation.

Comment: Using LINQ: `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the Local Network IP address of a computer programmatically? (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151231/how-do-i-get-the-local-network-ip-address-of-a-computer-programmatically-c)

Comment: This is a typical situation where users with completely different needs tend to ask the same question.  Some people want to know how their computer can be reached from the public network.  The canonical answer is [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), though many answer with hacks dependent on random third parties.  Some people just want to know their IP address(es) on local network(s).  Good answers in this case mention [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx).

Answer (score 240):

Nope, that is pretty much the best way to do it.  As a machine *could* have several IP addresses you need to iterate the collection of them to find the proper one.

**Edit:** The only thing I *would* change would be to change this:

```
if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
```

to this:

```
if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
```

There is no need to `ToString` an enumeration for comparison.

Comment: I want the external IP address, if possible. I suppose it's not going to be that possible if I am behind NAT.

Comment: No, your machine will only know its NAT address.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that you will need to reach an external server for the external address.

Comment: then, which is the best IP number I need to choose? The code in the question looked for "InterNetwork", is that the "best"?

Comment: I would also suggest a `break` statement after the IP has been found to avoid unnecessarily iterating further through the collection (in this case I doubt the performance impact will ever matter, but I like to stress generally good coding habits)

Comment: Note that this might fail when a machine has multiple 'InterNetwork' ports (In my case: an ethernet card an a virtual machine port). The current code will give you the last IP on the list.

Comment: U need to add using System.Net.Sockets

Comment: Problems with this code:
* It assumes a computer has only a single IP address. Many have multiple.
* It only considers IPV4 addresses. Add InterNetworkV6 to include IPV6.

Answer (score 170):

The only way to know your public IP is to ask someone else to tell you; this code may help you:

```
public string GetPublicIP()
{
    String direction = "";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Search for the ip in the html
    int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
    int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
    direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);

    return direction;
}
```

Comment: Do you know your code sample was mentioned in Question 13 Twenty C# Questions Explained of the Microsoft Academy?  The presenter apologizes for stealing your code. From 8:30 minutes onwards. See [this](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=8464&m=8456&ct=28536). :)

Comment: Unfortunately link is dead.

Comment: [New link](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/twenty-c-questions-answered-8298?l=JpBF7UYy_4104984382) in case anyone want's to see it

Comment: Please use link http://ipof.in/txt so you can get the IP a directly without all the HTML parsing code

Answer (score 83):

Cleaner and an all in one solution :D

```
//This returns the first IP4 address or null
return Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Comment: Problems with this code:
* It assumes a computer has only a single IP address. Many have multiple.
* It only considers IPV4 addresses. Add InterNetworkV6 to include IPV6.

Comment: @RobertBratton, Thank you for your replay. The problem did not not assume a multi IP address or IPV6, with slight modifications to this code it can handle specific different problems.

Answer (score 51):

If you can't rely on getting your IP address from a DNS server (which has happened to me), you can use the following approach:

The System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace contains a [NetworkInterface class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx), which has a static [GetAllNetworkInterfaces method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx).

This method will return all "network interfaces" on your machine, and there are generally quite a few, even if you only have a wireless adapter and/or an ethernet adapter hardware installed on your machine.  All of these network interfaces have valid IP addresses for your local machine, although you probably only want one.

If you're looking for one IP address, then you'll need to filter the list down until you can identify the right address.  You will probably need to do some experimentation, but I had success with the following approach:

- Filter out any NetworkInterfaces that are inactive by checking for `OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up`.  This will exclude your physical ethernet adapter, for instance, if you don't have a network cable plugged in.

For each NetworkInterface, you can get an [IPInterfaceProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.aspx) object using the [GetIPProperties method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getipproperties.aspx), and from an IPInterfaceProperties object you can access the [UnicastAddresses property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.unicastaddresses.aspx) for a list of [UnicastIPAddressInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation.aspx) objects.

- Filter out non-preferred unicast addresses by checking for `DuplicateAddressDetectionState == DuplicateAddressDetectionState.Preferred`
- Filter out "virtual" addresses by checking for `AddressPreferredLifetime != UInt32.MaxValue`.

At this point I take the address of the first (if any) unicast address that matches all of these filters.

### EDIT:

[revised code on May 16, 2018 to include the conditions mentioned in the text above for duplicate address detection state and preferred lifetime]

The sample below demonstrates filtering based on operational status, address family, excluding the loopback address (127.0.0.1), duplicate address detection state, and preferred lifetime.

```
static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetLocalIpAddresses()
{
    // Get the list of network interfaces for the local computer.
    var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    // Return the list of local IPv4 addresses excluding the local
    // host, disconnected, and virtual addresses.
    return (from adapter in adapters
            let properties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
            from address in properties.UnicastAddresses
            where adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
                  address.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork &&
                  !address.Equals(IPAddress.Loopback) &&
                  address.DuplicateAddressDetectionState == DuplicateAddressDetectionState.Preferred &&
                  address.AddressPreferredLifetime != UInt32.MaxValue
            select address.Address);
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, the OP wanted to see his external IP address, so the DNS solution is probably the way to go.  But for iterating local IP addresses, this is the approach I recommend.

Comment: Agreed that DNS is an easier way to get the IP address. I mentioned in my answer that this approach works when your DNS is unreliable. I used this in an environment where DNS was messed up such that if you moved a machine from one ethernet port to another, DNS would still report the old IP address, so it was nearly useless for my purposes.

Comment: I appreciate all the description, but you should have posted the code sample too.

Comment: Excellent thanks. Note that following recent Windows update, UnicastAddresses. **First** assumption no longer holds. I now need to check **all** UnicastAddress for each adaptor with further filtering using **AddressPreferredLifetime** and **DuplicateAddressDetectionStation** (mentioned in your text above)

Answer (score 37):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string IP = webClient.DownloadString("http://myip.ozymo.com/");
```

Comment: ifconfig.me/ip no longer works. Try https://api.ipify.org or the link in Doug's comment instead

Answer (score 16):

```
using System.Net;

string host = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList[0].ToString());
```

Just tested this on my machine and it works.

Comment: it will get u local ip,and question is about external IP i.e.Ip with which u browse internet..

Answer (score 15):

If you want to avoid using DNS:

```
List<IPAddress> ipList = new List<IPAddress>();
foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    foreach (var address in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
    {
        if (address.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found IP " + address.Address.ToString());
            ipList.Add(address.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't rely on InterNetwork all the time because you can have more than one device which also uses IP4 which would screw up the results in getting your IP.
Now, if you would like you may just copy this and please review it or update it to how you see fit.

First I get the address of the router (gateway)
If it comes back that I am connected to a gateway (which mean not connected directly into the modem wireless or not) then we have our gateway address as IPAddress else we a null pointer IPAddress reference.

Then we need to get the computer's list of IPAddresses. This is where things are not that hard because routers (all routers) use 4 bytes (...). The first three are the most important because any computer connected to it will have the IP4 address matching the first three bytes. Ex: 192.168.0.1 is standard for router default IP unless changed by the adminstrator of it. '192.168.0' or whatever they may be is what we need to match up. And that is all I did in IsAddressOfGateway function. 
The reason for the length matching is because not all addresses (which are for the computer only) have the length of 4 bytes. If you type in netstat in the cmd, you will find this to be true. So there you have it. Yes, it takes a little more work to really get what you are looking for. Process of elimination.
And for God's sake, do not find the address by pinging it which takes time because first you are sending the address to be pinged and then it has to send the result back. No, work directly with .Net classes which deal with your system environment and you will get the answers you are looking for when it has to solely do with your computer.

Now if you are directly connected to your modem, the process is almost the same because the modem is your gateway but the submask is not the same because your getting the information directly from your DNS Server via modem and not masked by the router serving up the Internet to you although you still can use the same code because the last byte of the IP assigned to the modem is 1. So if IP sent from the modem which does change is 111.111.111.1' then you will get 111.111.111.(some byte value). Keep in mind the we need to find the gateway information because there are more devices which deal with internet connectivity than your router and modem.

Now you see why you DON'T change your router's first two bytes 192 and 168. These are strictly distinguished for routers only and not internet use or we would have a serious issue with IP Protocol and double pinging resulting in crashing your computer. Image that your assigned router IP is 192.168.44.103 and you click on a site with that IP as well. OMG! Your computer would not know what to ping. Crash right there. To avoid this issue, only routers are assigned these and not for internet usage. So leave the first two bytes of the router alone.

```
static IPAddress FindLanAddress()
{
    IPAddress gateway = FindGetGatewayAddress();
    if (gateway == null)
        return null;

    IPAddress[] pIPAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (IPAddress address in pIPAddress)            {
        if (IsAddressOfGateway(address, gateway))
                return address;
    return null;
}
static bool IsAddressOfGateway(IPAddress address, IPAddress gateway)
{
    if (address != null && gateway != null)
        return IsAddressOfGateway(address.GetAddressBytes(),gateway.GetAddressBytes());
    return false;
}
static bool IsAddressOfGateway(byte[] address, byte[] gateway)
{
    if (address != null && gateway != null)
    {
        int gwLen = gateway.Length;
        if (gwLen > 0)
        {
            if (address.Length == gateway.Length)
            {
                --gwLen;
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < gwLen; i++)
                {
                    if (address[i] == gateway[i])
                        ++counter;
                }
                return (counter == gwLen);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
static IPAddress FindGetGatewayAddress()
{
    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobProps = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties ipInfProps = ni.GetIPProperties();
        foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation gi in ipInfProps.GatewayAddresses)
            return gi.Address;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense: foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation gi in ipInfProps.GatewayAddresses) return gi.Address;

Comment: There is no guarantee that "any computer connected to a gateway will have the IP4 address matching the first three bytes". It depends on the subnet mask, which can contain various bit combinations. And furthermore, starting bytes don't have to be "192.168", as [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). This code will only work if subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`, and it will do so in a rather complicated way IMO.

Answer (score 8):

I just thought that I would add my own, one-liner (even though there are many other useful answers already).

---

`string ipAddress = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");`

Comment: Note that this has a potential memory leak. The WebClient is not properly disposed of. Instead, use: using (var client = new WebClient()) { return client.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/").Trim(); }

Answer (score 4):

For getting the current public IP address, all you need to do is create an ASPX page with the following line on the page load event:

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are running in intranet you'll be able to get local machine IP address and if not you'll get external ip address with this:
Web:

```
//this will bring the IP for the current machine on browser
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Desktop:

```
//This one will bring all local IPs for the desired namespace
IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace NKUtilities 
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    public class DNSUtility
    {
        public static int Main(string [] args)
        {
            string strHostName = "";
            try {

                if(args.Length == 0)
                {
                    // Getting Ip address of local machine...
                    // First get the host name of local machine.
                    strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                    Console.WriteLine ("Local Machine's Host Name: " +  strHostName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise, get the IP address of the host provided on the command line.
                    strHostName = args[0];
                }

                // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
                IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry (strHostName);
                IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

                for(int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
                }
                return 0;

            } 
            catch(SocketException se) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", se.Message, strHostName);
                return -1;
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}.", ex.Message);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Look [here](http://www.netomatix.com/MachineIP.aspx) for details.

You have to remember your computer can have more than one IP (actually it always does) - so which one are you after.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
 String MyIp = localIPs[0].ToString();
```

Comment: This returns a number of local IP addresses, one of which is the IPv4 address, however its difficult to find the correct one in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by **external** IP you can consider (if you are in a Web server context) using this

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

I was asking the same question as you and I found it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345676/c-asp-net-how-to-get-the-server-ip-address/1345700) stackoverflow article.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace NKUtilities 
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;

    public class DNSUtility
    {
        public static int Main (string [] args)
        {

          String strHostName = new String ("");
          if (args.Length == 0)
          {
              // Getting Ip address of local machine...
              // First get the host name of local machine.
              strHostName = Dns.GetHostName ();
              Console.WriteLine ("Local Machine's Host Name: " +  strHostName);
          }
          else
          {
              strHostName = args[0];
          }

          // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
          IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName (strHostName);
          IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

          for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString ());
          }
          return 0;
        }    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace IPADDRESS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String strHostName = string.Empty;
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {                
                /* First get the host name of local machine.*/
                strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);
            }
            else
            {
                strHostName = args[0];
            }
            /* Then using host name, get the IP address list..*/
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Simple single line of code that returns the first internal IPV4 address or null if there are none. Added as a comment above, but may be useful to someone (some solutions above will return multiple addresses that need further filtering).

It's also easy to return loopback instead of null I guess with:

```
return Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) ?? new IPAddress( new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1} );
```

Comment: How about `IPAddress.Loopback`? :)

Answer (score 1):

To find IP address list I have used this solution

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAddresses()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    return (from ip in host.AddressList where ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.lo select ip.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

But I personally like below solution to get local *valid* IP address

```
public static IPAddress GetIPAddress(string hostName)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    var replay = ping.Send(hostName);

    if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        return replay.Address;
    }
    return null;
 }

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Local IP Address: " + GetIPAddress(Dns.GetHostName()));
    Console.WriteLine("Google IP:" + GetIPAddress("google.com");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ solution:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Select(ip => ip.ToString()).FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i solved it. i know if you have several physical interfaces this might not select the exact eth you want.

```
private string FetchIP()
{
    //Get all IP registered
    List<string> IPList = new List<string>();
    IPHostEntry host;
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            IPList.Add(ip.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Find the first IP which is not only local
    foreach (string a in IPList)
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        string[] b = a.Split('.');
        string ip2 = b[0] + "." + b[1] + "." + b[2] + ".1";
        PingReply t = p.Send(ip2);
        p.Dispose();
        if (t.Status == IPStatus.Success && ip2 != a)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't say ASP.NET MVC but I'm just leaving this here anyway:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: This only works if there's a request involved. What if it's a worker that runs on the server every couple hours?

Answer (score 1):

Get all IP addresses as strings using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
string[] allIpAddresses = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .SelectMany(c=>c.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
        .Where(d=>d.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        .Select(d=>d.Address.ToString())
    ).ToArray();
```

**TO FILTER OUT PRIVATE ONES...**

First, define an extension method `IsPrivate()`:

```
public static class IPAddressExtensions
{
    // Collection of private CIDRs (IpAddress/Mask) 
    private static Tuple<int, int>[] _privateCidrs = new []{"10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"}
        .Select(c=>Tuple.Create(BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress
                                    .Parse(c.Split('/')[0]).GetAddressBytes(), 0)
                              , IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(-1 << (32-int.Parse(c.Split('/')[1])))))
        .ToArray();
    public static bool IsPrivate(this IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        int ip = BitConverter.ToInt32(ipAddress.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
        return _privateCidrs.Any(cidr=>(ip & cidr.Item2)==(cidr.Item1 & cidr.Item2));           
    }
}
```

... And then use it to filter out private IPs:

```
string[] publicIpAddresses = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .SelectMany(c=>c.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
        .Where(d=>d.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
            && !d.Address.IsPrivate() // Filter out private ones
        )
        .Select(d=>d.Address.ToString())
    ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me... and should be faster in most case (if not all) than querying a DNS server. Thanks to Dr. Wily's Apprentice ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni/18283999)).

```
// ************************************************************************
/// <summary>
/// Will search for the an active NetworkInterafce that has a Gateway, otherwise
/// it will fallback to try from the DNS which is not safe.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static NetworkInterface GetMainNetworkInterface()
{
    List<NetworkInterface> candidates = new List<NetworkInterface>();

    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
            NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (
            NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
        {
            if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                candidates.Add(ni);
        }
    }

    if (candidates.Count == 1)
    {
        return candidates[0];
    }

    // Accoring to our tech, the main NetworkInterface should have a Gateway 
    // and it should be the ony one with a gateway.
    if (candidates.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int n = candidates.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
        {
            if (candidates[n].GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Count == 0)
            {
                candidates.RemoveAt(n);
            }
        }

        if (candidates.Count == 1)
        {
            return candidates[0];
        }
    }

    // Fallback to try by getting my ipAdress from the dns
    IPAddress myMainIpAdress = null;
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) // Get the first IpV4
        {
            myMainIpAdress = ip;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myMainIpAdress != null)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
            NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
        {
            if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties props = ni.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ai in props.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ai.Address.Equals(myMainIpAdress))
                    {
                        return ni;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// ******************************************************************
/// <summary>
/// AddressFamily.InterNetwork = IPv4
/// Thanks to Dr. Wilys Apprentice at
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni
/// using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mac"></param>
/// <param name="addressFamily">AddressFamily.InterNetwork = IPv4,  AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 = IPv6</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IPAddress GetIpFromMac(PhysicalAddress mac, AddressFamily addressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
    NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
        NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
    {
        if (ni.GetPhysicalAddress().Equals(mac))
        {
            if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties props = ni.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ai in props.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ai.DuplicateAddressDetectionState == DuplicateAddressDetectionState.Preferred)
                    {
                        if (ai.Address.AddressFamily == addressFamily)
                        {
                            return ai.Address;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// ******************************************************************
/// <summary>
/// Return the best guess of main ipAdress. To get it in the form aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd just call 
/// '?.ToString() ?? ""' on the result.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IPAddress GetMyInternetIpAddress()
{
    NetworkInterface ni = GetMainNetworkInterface();
    IPAddress ipAddress = GetIpFromMac(ni.GetPhysicalAddress());
    if (ipAddress == null) // could it be possible ?
    {
        ipAddress = GetIpFromMac(ni.GetPhysicalAddress(), AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
    }

    return ipAddress;
}

// ******************************************************************
```

Just as reference this is the full class code where I defined it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpMonitor
{
    /*
        Usage:
                var cons = TcpHelper.GetAllTCPConnections();
                foreach (TcpHelper.MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID c in cons) ...
    */

    public class NetHelper
    {
        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetExtendedUdpTable(IntPtr pUdpTable, ref int dwOutBufLen, bool sort, int ipVersion, UDP_TABLE_CLASS tblClass, uint reserved = 0);

        public enum UDP_TABLE_CLASS
        {
            UDP_TABLE_BASIC,
            UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID,
            UDP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint dwNumEntries;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
            public MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint localAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            public uint owningPid;

            public uint ProcessId
            {
                get { return owningPid; }
            }

            public IPAddress LocalAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(localAddr); }
            }

            public ushort LocalPort
            {
                get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(localPort.Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0); }
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_UDP6TABLE_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint dwNumEntries;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
            public MIB_UDP6ROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_UDP6ROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
            public byte[] localAddr;
            public uint localScopeId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            public uint owningPid;
            public uint ProcessId
            {
                get { return owningPid; }
            }

            public IPAddress LocalAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(localAddr, localScopeId); }
            }

            public ushort LocalPort
            {
                get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(localPort.Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0); }
            }
        }

        public static List<MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllUDPConnections()
        {
            return GetUDPConnections<MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID> (AF_INET);
        }

        public static List<MIB_UDP6ROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllUDPv6Connections()
        {
            return GetUDPConnections<MIB_UDP6ROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_UDP6TABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET6);
        }

        private static List<IPR> GetUDPConnections<IPR, IPT>(int ipVersion)//IPR = Row Type, IPT = Table Type
        {
            List<IPR> result = null;

            IPR[] tableRows = null;
            int buffSize = 0;

            var dwNumEntriesField = typeof(IPT).GetField("dwNumEntries");

            // how much memory do we need?
            uint ret = GetExtendedUdpTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, UDP_TABLE_CLASS.UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID);
            IntPtr udpTablePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);

            try
            {
                ret = GetExtendedUdpTable(udpTablePtr, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, UDP_TABLE_CLASS.UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID);
                if (ret != 0)
                    return new List<IPR>();

                // get the number of entries in the table
                IPT table = (IPT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(udpTablePtr, typeof(IPT));
                int rowStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IPR));
                uint numEntries = (uint)dwNumEntriesField.GetValue(table);

                // buffer we will be returning
                tableRows = new IPR[numEntries];

                IntPtr rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)udpTablePtr + 4);
                for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
                {
                    IPR tcpRow = (IPR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rowPtr, typeof(IPR));
                    tableRows[i] = tcpRow;
                    rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)rowPtr + rowStructSize);   // next entry
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                result = tableRows?.ToList() ?? new List<IPR>();

                // Free the Memory
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(udpTablePtr);
            }

            return result;
        }

        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable, ref int dwOutBufLen, bool sort, int ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS tblClass, uint reserved = 0);



        public enum MIB_TCP_STATE
        {
            MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED = 1,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_LISTEN = 2,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT = 3,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD = 4,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB = 5,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT1 = 6,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2 = 7,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT = 8,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSING = 9,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK = 10,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT = 11,
            MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB = 12
        }

        public enum TCP_TABLE_CLASS
        {
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_ALL,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_ALL
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint dwNumEntries;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
            public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint dwNumEntries;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
            public MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint state;
            public uint localAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            public uint remoteAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] remotePort;
            public uint owningPid;

            public uint ProcessId
            {
                get { return owningPid; }
            }

            public IPAddress LocalAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(localAddr); }
            }

            public ushort LocalPort
            {
                get
                {
                    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] { localPort[1], localPort[0] }, 0);
                }
            }

            public IPAddress RemoteAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(remoteAddr); }
            }

            public ushort RemotePort
            {
                get
                {
                    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] { remotePort[1], remotePort[0] }, 0);
                }
            }

            public MIB_TCP_STATE State
            {
                get { return (MIB_TCP_STATE)state; }
            }
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
            public byte[] localAddr;
            public uint localScopeId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
            public byte[] remoteAddr;
            public uint remoteScopeId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] remotePort;
            public uint state;
            public uint owningPid;

            public uint ProcessId
            {
                get { return owningPid; }
            }

            public long LocalScopeId
            {
                get { return localScopeId; }
            }

            public IPAddress LocalAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(localAddr, LocalScopeId); }
            }

            public ushort LocalPort
            {
                get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(localPort.Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0); }
            }

            public long RemoteScopeId
            {
                get { return remoteScopeId; }
            }

            public IPAddress RemoteAddress
            {
                get { return new IPAddress(remoteAddr, RemoteScopeId); }
            }

            public ushort RemotePort
            {
                get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(remotePort.Take(2).Reverse().ToArray(), 0); }
            }

            public MIB_TCP_STATE State
            {
                get { return (MIB_TCP_STATE)state; }
            }
        }


        public const int AF_INET = 2;    // IP_v4 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        public const int AF_INET6 = 23;  // IP_v6 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6

        public static Task<List<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID>> GetAllTCPConnectionsAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET));
        }

        public static List<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllTCPConnections()
        {
            return GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET);
        }

        public static Task<List<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID>> GetAllTCPv6ConnectionsAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(()=>GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET6));
        }

        public static List<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllTCPv6Connections()
        {
            return GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET6);
        }

        private static List<IPR> GetTCPConnections<IPR, IPT>(int ipVersion)//IPR = Row Type, IPT = Table Type
        {
            List<IPR> result = null;

            IPR[] tableRows = null;
            int buffSize = 0;

            var dwNumEntriesField = typeof(IPT).GetField("dwNumEntries");

            // how much memory do we need?
            uint ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);
            IntPtr tcpTablePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);

            try
            {
                ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTablePtr, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);
                if (ret != 0)
                    return new List<IPR>();

                // get the number of entries in the table
                IPT table = (IPT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcpTablePtr, typeof(IPT));
                int rowStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IPR));
                uint numEntries = (uint)dwNumEntriesField.GetValue(table);

                // buffer we will be returning
                tableRows = new IPR[numEntries];

                IntPtr rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tcpTablePtr + 4);
                for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
                {
                    IPR tcpRow = (IPR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rowPtr, typeof(IPR));
                    tableRows[i] = tcpRow;
                    rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)rowPtr + rowStructSize);   // next entry
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                result = tableRows?.ToList() ?? new List<IPR>();

                // Free the Memory
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcpTablePtr);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static string GetTcpStateName(MIB_TCP_STATE state)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED:
                    return "Closed";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_LISTEN:
                    return "Listen";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT:
                    return "SynSent";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD:
                    return "SynReceived";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB:
                    return "Established";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT1:
                    return "FinWait 1";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2:
                    return "FinWait 2";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT:
                    return "CloseWait";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSING:
                    return "Closing";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK:
                    return "LastAck";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT:
                    return "TimeWait";
                case MIB_TCP_STATE.MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB:
                    return "DeleteTCB";
                default:
                    return ((int)state).ToString();
            }
        }

        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> DicOfIpToHostName = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public const string UnknownHostName = "Unknown";

        // ******************************************************************
        public static string GetHostName(IPAddress ipAddress)
        {
            return GetHostName(ipAddress.ToString());
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        public static string GetHostName(string ipAddress)
        {
            string hostName = null;

            if (!DicOfIpToHostName.TryGetValue(ipAddress, out hostName))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ipAddress == "0.0.0.0" || ipAddress == "::")
                    {
                        hostName = ipAddress;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress).HostName;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                    hostName = UnknownHostName;
                }

                DicOfIpToHostName[ipAddress] = hostName;
            }

            return hostName;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Will search for the an active NetworkInterafce that has a Gateway, otherwise
        /// it will fallback to try from the DNS which is not safe.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static NetworkInterface GetMainNetworkInterface()
        {
            List<NetworkInterface> candidates = new List<NetworkInterface>();

            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
                    NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

                foreach (
                    NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
                {
                    if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                        candidates.Add(ni);
                }
            }

            if (candidates.Count == 1)
            {
                return candidates[0];
            }

            // Accoring to our tech, the main NetworkInterface should have a Gateway 
            // and it should be the ony one with a gateway.
            if (candidates.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int n = candidates.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
                {
                    if (candidates[n].GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Count == 0)
                    {
                        candidates.RemoveAt(n);
                    }
                }

                if (candidates.Count == 1)
                {
                    return candidates[0];
                }
            }

            // Fallback to try by getting my ipAdress from the dns
            IPAddress myMainIpAdress = null;
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) // Get the first IpV4
                {
                    myMainIpAdress = ip;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (myMainIpAdress != null)
            {
                NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
                    NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

                foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
                {
                    if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        IPInterfaceProperties props = ni.GetIPProperties();
                        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ai in props.UnicastAddresses)
                        {
                            if (ai.Address.Equals(myMainIpAdress))
                            {
                                return ni;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// AddressFamily.InterNetwork = IPv4
        /// Thanks to Dr. Wilys Apprentice at
        /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni
        /// using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mac"></param>
        /// <param name="addressFamily">AddressFamily.InterNetwork = IPv4,  AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 = IPv6</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IPAddress GetIpFromMac(PhysicalAddress mac, AddressFamily addressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterfaces =
                NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterfaces)
            {
                if (ni.GetPhysicalAddress().Equals(mac))
                {
                    if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        IPInterfaceProperties props = ni.GetIPProperties();
                        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ai in props.UnicastAddresses)
                        {
                            if (ai.DuplicateAddressDetectionState == DuplicateAddressDetectionState.Preferred)
                            {
                                if (ai.Address.AddressFamily == addressFamily)
                                {
                                    return ai.Address;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Return the best guess of main ipAdress. To get it in the form aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd just call 
        /// '?.ToString() ?? ""' on the result.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IPAddress GetMyInternetIpAddress()
        {
            NetworkInterface ni = GetMainNetworkInterface();
            IPAddress ipAddress = GetIpFromMac(ni.GetPhysicalAddress());
            if (ipAddress == null) // could it be possible ?
            {
                ipAddress = GetIpFromMac(ni.GetPhysicalAddress(), AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
            }

            return ipAddress;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        public static bool IsBroadcastAddress(IPAddress ipAddress)
        {
            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ipAddress.GetAddressBytes()[3] == 255;
            }

            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                return false; // NO broadcast in IPv6
            }

            return false;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        public static bool IsMulticastAddress(IPAddress ipAddress)
        {
            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                // Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772041(v=ws.10).aspx
                return ipAddress.GetAddressBytes()[0] >= 224 && ipAddress.GetAddressBytes()[0] <= 239;
            }

            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                return ipAddress.IsIPv6Multicast;
            }

            return false;
        }

        // ******************************************************************

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to get your public IP address is to use OpenDNS's `resolve1.opendns.com` server with `myip.opendns.com` as the request.

On the command line this is:

```
  nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

Or in C# using the DNSClient nuget:

```
  var lookup = new LookupClient(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 208, 67, 222, 222 }));
  var result = lookup.Query("myip.opendns.com", QueryType.ANY);
```

This is a bit cleaner than hitting http endpoints and parsing responses.

Answer (score 0):

And this is to get all local IPs in csv format in VB.NET

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Function GetIPAddress() As String
    Dim ipList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim host As IPHostEntry
    Dim localIP As String = "?"
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    For Each ip As IPAddress In host.AddressList
        If ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            localIP = ip.ToString()
            ipList.Add(localIP)
        End If
    Next
    Dim ret As String = String.Join(",", ipList.ToArray)
    Return ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the remote ip address the quickest way possible. You must have to use a downloader, or create a server on your computer.

The downsides to using this simple code: (which is recommended) is that it will take 3-5 seconds to get your Remote IP Address because the WebClient when initialized always takes 3-5 seconds to check for your proxy settings.

```
 public static string GetIP()
 {
            string externalIP = "";
            externalIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                                           .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
            return externalIP;
 }
```

Here is how I fixed it.. (first time still takes 3-5 seconds) but after that it will always get your Remote IP Address in 0-2 seconds depending on your connection.

```
public static WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
public static string GetIP()
{
    string externalIP = "";
    externalIP = webclient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
    externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                                   .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
    return externalIP;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? you cannot find a answer faster or better then this.. initializating the WebClient everytime has a big overhead delay no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string GetLocalIpAdresse()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach(var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception  ("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system");
    }
```