# How to get ip address from .Net code

Tags: c#, .net

I just want to get the System IP address and display it on a UI.Can someone please tell the API to be used for the same

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
internal IPAddress[] GetIPAddresses()
{
    string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ihe = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    return ihe.AddressList;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
                 .FirstOrDefault(addr => !IPAddress.IsLoopback(addr));
Console.WriteLine(address);
```

(this code excludes the local address 127.0.0.1)

Comment: You may want to change .First to .FirstOrDefault, in case the computer has no IP.