# How to get IP address of server in .NET?

Tags: .net, webserver, ip-address

How do you get the IP address of the web/application server in .NET? Not the client IP address, but the server IP address.

---

I just found something about [server variables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp).

Comment: Do you want the External IP address? The IP Address on the local network? The IP address of the URL the originating request went to?

Comment: @McKay I'm looking for the External IP Address of the web server.

Comment: So, the problem is that the external IP address of the server isn't something that the server itself knows about. It's something the external hardware knows about. My external IP address is controlled by my ISP. I happen to know what it is, but I can't directly get it.

Comment: @McKay Interesting... well how about the internal IP address, know how to get that?

Comment: I guess the real question is "What do you want this for?"

Comment: NeilDurant's answer covers "internal" IP address.

Comment: Would it be possible to host a service outside of the enclave? That way you could call it and the service you called would respond with the IP that it saw the request originate from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like the following code, to get all IP addresses of the current machine.  However it won't tell you which network adaptor (and thus IP address) a particular request came in on, if you have more than one.

```
   String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
   Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + strHostName);

   // Find host by name
   IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

   // Enumerate IP addresses
   foreach(IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ipaddress.ToString());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get [my own IP address in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

```
IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName (Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
```

To get for other's machine

```
IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName (strHostName);
IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are services that tell you what your external IP address is, but it might be subject to change.

Sample Services:

- http://www.whatismyip.com/
- http://www.dnsstuff.com/

Answer (score -2):

To get the IP address (and Coutnry/location) of a server programatically I use Utrace.de API. It returns an XML with IP address and location information too.

Example query: http://xml.utrace.de/?query=google.com

Comment: I think he's looking for discovering the IP address of his current server, and doesn't know how to get data to pass to utrace.de

Comment: ooh.. I got it. i should have given example of domain name.. rather than IP.