# How can I get computer name and IP address of local computer

Tags: c#

How can I get the computer name and IP address of my PC programmatically?  For example, I want to display that information in a text box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the IP address of the server on which my C# application is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)

and this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx)

```
textBox1.Text = "Computer Name: " + Environment.MachineName

textBox2.Text = "IP Add: " + Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)[0].ToString();
```

Comment: get the ipaddress of your own machine is passible, how to get other machine ipaddress, while they login our application?

Comment: `Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)` simply returns an array of all addresses for the current host. Picking `[0]` of that array is not helpful--especially when the host can have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This doesn't even factor in private (internal network) vs public (external network) addresses. Forget about if the host is using > 0 VPNs. Picking the first element of this array is useless.

Comment: Redact my comments in full--the concerns have already been addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni

Answer (score 3):

Check more about this : [How To Get IP Address Of A Machine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/network.aspx)

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;


string strName = p.Identity.Name;


To get the machine name,


System.Environment.MachineName 
or
using System.Net;
strHostName = DNS.GetHostName ();


// Then using host name, get the IP address list..
IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName (strHostName);
IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In easy way..

```
string IP_Address = Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[0].toString();
```

Comment: does not return human readable iv4

Answer (score 0):

I use the following found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376368/2510099
for the IP address

```
public string GetIPAddress()
{    
   string ipAddress = null;

   using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
   {
      socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530); //Google public DNS and port
      IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
      ipAddress = endPoint.Address.ToString();
   }

   return ipAddress;
}
```

and for the machine name

```
Environment.MachineName;
```

Comment: This is a very clever idea, and I think it would work for a lot of folks. If, however, you want to know the private IP address that your system is using to communicate between other systems, this technique will not help.