# How to check if DNS server is set to 'obtain automatically'

Tags: c#, dns, wmi

When I get my servers DNS settings using the DNSServerSearchOrder property of my network card's settings, it returns the DNS server that it automatically resolves to, rather than a value that would indicate it is dynamic (such as null).

for example, to set my DNS servers to 'Obtain Automatically' I do:

```
ManagementBaseObject newDNS = myNICManagementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
ManagementBaseObject setDNS = myNICManagementObject.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
```

Now, after I have set it to 'Obtain Automatically' with the other command I want to confirm it was set:

```
if( myNICManagementObject["DNSServerSearchOrder"] == null )
{
    MessageBox.Show("DNS Servers Set to Dynamic!");
}
```

However, the above code does not return null (nor pop-up a messagebox) as expected. Instead it returns the DNS server that it dynamically figures out from my ISP.

Is there a way to determine programmatically that my DNS servers are set to 'Obtain Automatically'?

Comment: I read that post before I asked my question and have now re-read it but still do not see anything that can answer my question

Comment: I also have the same question. I think that there must be an way to get this information.
If you type in `netsh interface ip show config` then you'll see, that netsh is able to differentiate the source of the dns servers.
I even thought of parsing the results from netsh, but this doesn't work, if someone uses my program with windows installation which has another localization package...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I found is to read from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\\{Network_Adaptor_GUID}\NameServer
```

If `NameServer` is empty - then DNS is dynamic, otherwise - static.

Comment: This fails for empty manual DNS address.
In this scenario netsh correctly identifies the configuration as static (192.168.1.1).

Comment: I'd like to notice that netsh also shows static for L2TP connections.

Comment: If the user sets the DNS server manually on the Wi-Fi profile rather than on the adapter then NameServer is also empty, but ProfileNameServer is not.

Answer (score 1):

Vad's answer saved me a ton of time hunting for a solution. Here's some C# if anyone wants to see a very basic implementation.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
//...
private void DNSAutoOrStatic(string NetworkAdapterGUID)
        {
            string path = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\" + NetworkAdapterGUID;
            string ns = (string)Registry.GetValue(path, "NameServer", null);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ns))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dynamic DNS");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Static DNS: " + ns);
            }
        }
```

You can get the network adapter GUID following [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address).

It's the value of the Id property in `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface`