# C# Service Run Process on condition

Tags: c#, .net, service

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** 
I have the following code so far that works as for testing purposes. 
I need to be able to run the process that I have in my code after start-up and only when my DHCP lease is renewed/released or (I guess checking for change in IP address.)
That being said, things I need help with:

- **ONE:** how to have a thread task perform in timed intervals, (** a comment below has provided some help **)

  - **TWO:**  Figure out if my DHCP lease has changed/renewed/released since the service has started.
    I apologize for any confusion before thank you.*

**EDIT UPDATE:** I Have updated my Code, and honestly I have the timer figured out, I just need help figuring out the best way to know when or if the dhcp lease has been renewed/released&renewed/IP changed from before so I can see if when I check with the timed interval if it has changed to run the exe.

**CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace MyWindowsService
{
  class Program : ServiceBase
  {
    private static Process p = new Process();
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    //private static Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Set the location of the DHCP_Opion text creater.
      p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\NetLog\DHCPSolution-Option120.exe");
      ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
    }

    public Program()
    {
      this.ServiceName = "New_Service_Test";
      p.Start();
      // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
      aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);

      // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
      aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

      // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
      aTimer.Interval = 30000;
      aTimer.Enabled = true;
      //Garbarge collection.
      GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      //TODO: place your start code here
      base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
      //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
      base.OnStop();
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
         p.Start();
         p.WaitForExit();
    }
  }
}
```

**EDITED: FOR CLARIFICATION.**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: this question should be repharased a little bit.. can you specify in 3 sentences what you wish to achieve ?

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, check out System.Timers.Timer. When your process starts, start up a timer that checks every X seconds or minutes for what you want and starts up a process once your condition is met. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: Be specific in where you struck and what you need, make it clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you want to run the program when the lease expires and is renewed, or only if the IP address changed.

If you want to know when the IP address changed, you get the IP address when the program starts, and then check it every timer interval. So, you'd write:

```
private static string CurrentIPAddress;

public Program()
{
    this.ServiceName = "New_Service_Test";
    CurrentIpAddress = LocalIPAddress();
    p.Start();

    // initialize timer, etc.
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string myIp = LocalIPAddress();
    if (myIp == CurrentIPAddress)
    {
        // hasn't changed.
        break;
    }
    CurrentIpAddress = myIp;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

And the `LocalIpAddress` method comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803109/56778

You could eliminate all that polling by registering an event handler with the [NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) class. The `NetworkAddressChanged` event will fire whenever the IP address changes. The MSDN topic has a good example.

If you want to determine when the DHCP lease is renewed even if the IP address didn't change, you'll probably have to dig into the WMI interface, which I know very little about.

Comment: Network address changed ended up being a viable solution. Thank you very much.