# Retrieve IP address of device

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, ip-address

I am using Xamarin.Android and wrote the following code:

```
public TextView text;
text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.viewIP);
foreach (IPAddress adress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
{
    text.Text = "IP Adress: " + adress;
}
```

However, when I open the application it shuts down immediately. Am I using the correct way of getting the IP address' of the device?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2260/get-current-ip-address)

```
Java.Util.IEnumeration networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces;

while(networkInterfaces.HasMoreElements)
{
  Java.Net.NetworkInterface netInterface = 
                            (Java.Net.NetworkInterface)networkInterfaces.NextElement();
  Console.WriteLine(netInterface.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

added to mainifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

for get local ip:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
}
```

See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803109/4349342

Comment: You really wanna throw an exception because of that?  Hint - you don't.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers I've seen to this question have only gotten the internal IP address of my device while on my home network (198.162.#.#). So I took a slightly different approach, and ask the internet more directly. ipify.org has a nice and simple endpoint for getting your IP address, that can be executed in your shared code. For example...

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpResult>(resultString);

var yourIp = result.Ip;
```

Where "IpResult" is a POCO with a single string property named "Ip" (that you need to create, in addition to this code.)

Comment: what if the link gets down at some point? and is there no way at all to get the public IP Address without having to hit any link?

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked in PCL Xamarin:

```
public static string GetIPAddress()
{
    var AllNetworkInterfaces = Collections.List(Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);
    var IPAddres = "";
    foreach (var interfaces in AllNetworkInterfaces)
    {
        if (!(interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).Name.Contains("eth0")) continue;

        var AddressInterface = (interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).InterfaceAddresses;
        foreach (var AInterface in AddressInterface)
        {
            if(AInterface.Broadcast != null)
                IPAddres = AInterface.Address.HostAddress;
        }
    }
        return IPAddres;
}
```