# How to get Public IP Address in Xamarin Andorid, IOS and WPF without calling an External API

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, ip-address

I've been searching for a way to get the Public IP address with C# in Xamarin Android,IOS and WPF without calling an external API. I need to be able to get the users IP Address without calling an external API because waiting for response from an external API may take a time and my Apps are very dependent on getting the users IP address.

Comment: What qualifies as an "external API"?  External to *what*?

Comment: @Amy A web API specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve IP address of device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615022/retrieve-ip-address-of-device)