# Get currently working ip address

Tags: c#

I am seeking for a solution which allows me to get the currently working/(in use) ip address of my pc/laptop.

What I mean is I might be in LAN and then switch to WLAN. The ip addy will change and I need to stay up to date.

That is why I am not happy with approaches I found on the internet like IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: that is how to obtain local ip address.. its not the same. I am asking for currently in use

Comment: Try this : 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress

Comment: As far as I know there is no reliable method to figure this out from within the LAN. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: Why do you "need" this information and how will you use it? By the time your program obtains the information, it may be out of date (because connecting/disconnecting from networks are outside of the control of your program)

Comment: Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up the active interfaces of the machine like this:

```
var interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(a => a.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

var addresses = interfaces.First().GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Where(a => a.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

The `Address` property of any item in `addresses` holds the ip. From there you could monitor the adapters and decide when you need to switch over and what address to bind to.