# Entity Framework New GUID database initializer

Tags: entity-framework, guid

I want to initialize new GUID with my model class. I can not initialize GUID, Last Login IP adress.

Initializer doesn't create Kullanici table's row on database. Why ? I don't understand.

How can I add new row with GUID, IP Adress, `DateTime.Now` and more? Can you help me for that, please?

I'm using Entity Framework 6, MVC 5, SQL Server 2012, and ASP.NET 4.

**Kullanici.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace agiEmlak.Entities
{
    public class Kullanici
    {
        //public Kullanici()
        //{
        //    GID = Guid.NewGuid();
        //}
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public Guid GID { get; set; }
        public string KullaniciAdi { get; set; }
        public string Ad { get; set; }
        public string Soyad { get; set; }
        public string Sifre { get; set; }
        public string Eposta { get; set; }
        public DateTime KayitTarihi { get; set; }
        public string SonIPAdres { get; set; }
        public DateTime SonLoginTarihi { get; set; }
        public string AktivasyonKodu { get; set; }
        public string CepTelefonu { get; set; }
        public string IsTelefonu { get; set; }
        public bool? Aktif { get; set; }
        public bool? Silinmis { get; set; }

        public string AdSoyad
        {
            get
            {
                return Ad + " " + Soyad;
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Emlak> Emlaks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ilanInitializer.cs**:

```
using agiEmlak.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace agiEmlak.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class ilanInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ilanDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ilanDBContext context)
        {
            var kullanicilar = new List<Kullanici>
            {
            new Kullanici{ GID=Guid.NewGuid(), KullaniciAdi="halilkoca", Ad="Halil", Soyad="Koca", Eposta="halilkoca@outlook.com", Sifre="12551255", CepTelefonu="05415013031", IsTelefonu="02526133428", KayitTarihi=DateTime.Parse("25/10/2015"), AktivasyonKodu="5", SonIPAdres=Dns.GetHostName().ToString(), SonLoginTarihi= DateTime.Now},
            new Kullanici{ GID=Guid.NewGuid(), KullaniciAdi="halil", Ad="Halil", Soyad="Koca", Eposta="halilkoca.ilan@gmail.com", Sifre="12551255", CepTelefonu="05415013031", IsTelefonu="02526133428", KayitTarihi=DateTime.Parse("26/10/2015"), AktivasyonKodu="10", SonIPAdres=Dns.GetHostName().ToString(), SonLoginTarihi= DateTime.Now}
            };

            kullanicilar.ForEach(s => context.Kullanicis.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

**ilanDbContext.cs**:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using agiEmlak.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace agiEmlak.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class ilanDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public ilanDBContext(): base("ilanDBContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Adres> Adress { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ayar> Ayars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Detay> Detays { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DetayTaksonomi> DetayTaksonomis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Emlak> Emlaks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmlakKonutTuruMapping> EmlakKonutTuruMappings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmlakTipi> EmlakTipis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmlakTuru> EmlakTurus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Il> Ils { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ilce> Ilces { get; set; }
        public DbSet<KonutTipi> KonutTipis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Kullanici> Kullanicis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Mahalle> Mahalles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ozellik> Ozelliks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OzellikMapping> OzellikMappings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OzellikTaksonomi> OzellikTaksonomis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ulke> Ulkes { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Database üzerine Tablo isimleri tekil olarak kaydedilir.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**:

Add `Seed` method execute to `Global.asax.cs`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ilanDBContext>(new ilanInitializer());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `Seed` method executed? If not you have forgotten to specify that `ilanInitializer` is the DbInitializer for the `ilanDbContext'. see: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/814618/Use-of-Database-SetInitializer-method-in-Code-Firs

Comment: global.asax:
Database.SetInitializer<ilanDBContext>(new ilanInitializer());
it works bro, thanks a lot

Comment: you say "I can not initialize GUID, Last Login IP adress."... what error messages are you getting?

Comment: 'GUID' created, but I can't get user IP Address still. I work on it for now @Heberda , thanks.

Comment: So are you asking, how to store their IP address or how to retrieve it?

Comment: @Heberda yes I find this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address) Now, I try