# store IPV4 address in sqlserver in c# from various host but still same address are stored

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have used this code but same ipv4 address are stored where IP address and location etc. are difference of each machine. please check

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }
```

Comment: this 192.168.1.10 stored for all client

Comment: Isn't return causing this? As it will return first match and get out of loop? Plus what is the logic to store?

Comment: there are sample insert query

Comment: I have check this in local on two different network then store various Local IP but after hosting on server it store 192.168.1.10  for each client machine transnational data.

Comment: What is the SQL type  you are using for storing the values?

Comment: [LocalIP] [varchar](20) NULL

Comment: The code piece and question text is too less to provide solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get local IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address)