# Why does ip.AddressList contain two ip addresses?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dns, ip-address

This is my program to display the ip address of a system.

```
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress[] IPaddr = ip.AddressList;
for (int i = 0; i < IPaddr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IPaddr[i].ToString());
}
```

This displays the below output:

```
IP Address 0: fe80::90da:c637:d34a:c8a3%2
IP Address 1: 10.0.2.6
```

Why does this display two values? Isn't the second one the real ip address?

Comment: Machines can have multiple IP addresses. The first one listed here is an IPV6 address, the second is an IPV4 - machines can have any number of either kind.

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address