# Defining the outbound IP on the fly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am accessing a token generator that generates a token based on my IP (and my username & password). Since my code is running on App Service on Azure, it might use any of the out bound IPs that has been mentioned in [the app service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/).

How can I understand which IP am I using at a time? I'm thinking of storing the token in a dictionary for each IP and then using it.

Is there any better way?

### [What I've found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address)

One is like below, but first, I don't like opening a socket separably every time. Secondly, is the IP the same on every call?

```
using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
{
    socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
    localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
}
```

Is **local IP** the outbound or the inbound IP? I've also found this:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}
```

Comment: Each stamp App Service is hosted on has 4 or more outbound IP addresses, they're listed in the portal -- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/. Allocation is random, but never outside that list. There's not much to do here, a dictionary won't help since you don't know your outbound IP beforehand. Talk to those guys, they need to be a bit more relaxed with their token logic. This isn't 2005 any more.

Comment: @evilSnobu do you know if the IP stays the same if I call 2 backend services in the same API call?

Comment: Even if that may be true in tests, since there's no guarantee for stickiness, it's a bad start.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I understand which IP am I using at a time?

AFAIK, you could not make sure what the IP you current use when generate a token.

**This selection is not configurable** and the selection algorithm should be considered to **be random**. You can designate a specific IP address for outbound as described in combined scenarios.

For more details, read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#multivipsnat).

You could modify the rule of your token generator about how to generate token base on your IP address.

And try to change the single IP address to the **outbound IP address group**. So that, no matter which IP, the token could match with all the outbound IP addresses.

Comment: The token generator is not under his control, he's calling into it from App Service, which may pick any of the 4 or 5 public outbound IP Addresses when making the connection.