# C# - Get IP Address which has specified DNS server name

Tags: c#

How to get IP Address which has DNS (Specified)?, because it connected to specific domain network. Which i can view in command prompt using command "ipconfig /all"

Seperately i can retrieve the DNS server and its IP Addresses, HostName and its IP Addresses.

I would like to get the IP Address of hostmachine which has the DNS server name.

Code used,

```
string domainName = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
if (domainName == "oogway.net")
{
        //IP Address of hostmachine
}
```

#### Image reference about to get IP of domain name:

[image: IP Address of domain name]

---

I want to get only this IP address which is connected to network. Other VM IP Addresses are my machine which does not has domain name "oogway.net"

Image reference Other IP in same machine:
[image: Other IP in same machine]

---

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to find out which of the systems local IP addresses resolve to a given hostname?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address

Comment: [`Ping.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: You can ping using computer name to get the IP address.

Comment: Hi @PhonicUK, now you could understand. But sorry my english may not be good.

Comment: Hi @ArslanAli, link provided by you to get all IP address from machine. but mine is different from that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look,it's a way to get those values but it's a custom method which you have made choice for your own way as you want,

- Create Batch File with Name **file.bat** and write **ipconfig /all** command
  inside it.
- Make the Process of std out for getting output string from batch file
  to run it programmatically.After that,you will get string of output
  and split it for finding IPv4,Mac etc as showing you, following code
  to be tested.But you can customize for your own better choice.

  ```
      Process p = new Process();
      p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      p.StartInfo.FileName = "file.bat";
      p.Start();
      string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      p.WaitForExit();
      string[] splits = output.Split('\n');
      List<string> results = new List<string>();
      foreach (string s in splits)
      {
          var twoParts = s.Split(':');
          if (twoParts.Length == 2)
          {
              //Here you will apply checks for IP address and other mac etc
              //after that add those values to result list and get on last
              if (twoParts[0].Contains("IPv4"))
                  results.Add(twoParts[1]);
              else if (twoParts[0].Contains("Physical"))
                  results.Add(twoParts[1]);
              else if (twoParts[0].Contains("DNS"))
                  results.Add(twoParts[1]);
              else if (twoParts[0].Contains("Subnet Mask"))
                  results.Add(twoParts[1]);
          }
      }
      string data = "";
      foreach (var d in results)
      {
          data += d + "\n";
      }
      MessageBox.Show(data);
  ```