# How to get the local IP of the PC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, networking

I want to get the IP of my PC (the local IP taken from the router).

I could get the IP but with other IPs on the network. Is there a method to extract only the needed IP without getting all the IPs in an array and then choosing from them the needed one?

### Code tried:

```
string strHostName = string.Empty;
strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
IPAddress[] address = ipHostEntry.AddressList;

foreach (var item in address)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

The result of this code is a bunch of IPs found on the network including my IP (broadcast domain, IPv6 and similar stuff but not other devices' IPs). I want to get only my actual IP without getting all as the code will be published on a machine which I cannot monitor the IP all the time.

Comment: *The* ip does not exist, it depends on the number of interfaces on your system. You should take care of all of them or specifically look for one interface.

Comment: And if you want to know the IP Address of the interface that you connect to the internet with, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376368/9363973) SO answer has a solution to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing to filter the IP by type (v4). Anyway you can have multiple IP v4 addresses on your PC (for example you can have 2 interfaces, LAN and Wi-Fi).

The following code gets the list of available IP v4.

```
List<string> ips = new List<string>();

System.Net.IPHostEntry entry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());

foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in entry.AddressList)
    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        ips.Add(ip.ToString());
```