# How to find the network interface for a given local IP address

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

There are many questions about how to find the local IP address, how to find the IP address for a given network interface, but I need to find the network interface to which an IP address belongs, for example to get status changes for this interface.

So, how do I get the network interface to which an given IP address is assigned to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get local IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address)

Comment: Of course not. Read the question. I am not asking for the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace I came to the following solution:

```
public static NetworkInterface GetInterfaceForIP(IPAddress address)
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                if (address.Equals(ip.Address))
                    return ni;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Without much error checking here, this function returns the network interface for the IP.

If you need to check for status change events (cable unplugged, etc) can use the `NetworkChange` event in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace.