# Handling IP change on server side TCPListener Socket

Tags: c#, .net

I am using TcpListener class to create a TCP socket on a certain IP and port in my machine. The code I use is as follows :

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener("192.168.0.110", 8005);
try
{
    tcpListener.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    return;
}
```

This works fine. I want to use a check thread to check the status of the listener.

```
private void CheckConnections()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_tcpListener.Server.IsBound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_tcpListener.Active);
            Console.WriteLine("IsBound : True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_tcpListener.Active);
            Console.WriteLine("IsBound : False");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

When I change the IP of my machine manually from adapter settings, for example from "192.168.0.110" to "192.168.0.105", in the "netstat -ano" command I still see that the " 192.168.0.110:8005" is in Listening state. Also I could not find a way to subscribe to this change from my code. So my question is how to handle IP change on server side socket? Is there a way that I can get IP change information from the socket itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets remain in listening state for a while after being closed.  This is deliberate and is due to the way sockets have been designed.  it doesn't mean your code is still listening, it means the O/S is listening and it will eventually go away.

As for the second part of the question, you can listen to the [NotifyAddrChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/receiving-notification-of-network-events) notification, close your socket, and reopen on the new address.

Here is an article on how to do it.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35137/How-to-use-NotifyAddrChange-in-C

Comment: By the help of this comment, i decided to subscribe to NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event and handle the IP change there. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.
Try to use `TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8005);`
This will accept any IPAddress so you don't have to change it on code everytime.
Unless you want to change it while the program is running, that will be a little bit more complicated. You would have to close the socket and change the IP.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to "handle" IP change that is caused by other reasons rather than my program. If the IP address changes I need to be aware of that and inform the user about it. Because to clients of that TcpListener will not be able to reach it anymore.

Comment: Try to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address after and before, store it in a variable. and create a if running the background