# No local IP found

Tags: c#, system.net

I want to get the local IP-Address from any Windows device. It works fine for my Desktop-PC. But when I try to get the IP of my laptop or my surface I always get `123.123.123.123`.

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
    if (nInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet && nInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        foreach (var ip in nInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                return ip.Address;
}

return IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.123"); // Only for visualization, that none of the addresses fulfilled the conditions
```

Do I need to add another NetworkInterfaceType?

Comment: Looks similar to this problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address I would check and see if the approved answer resolves your issues.

Comment: I already tried it using DNS. Same problem

Comment: I note that this code only deals with IPv4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is effectively asking for Wired Ethernet IPs only.  Most of the time, a laptop won't have a Wired Ethernet address, but rather have a Wifi adapter with an address.  So, you can either look for the Wireless IP:

```cs
foreach (NetworkInterface nInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (nInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        // Using a switch statement to make it a litte easier to change the logic
        switch (nInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)
        {
            case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
            case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
                foreach (var ip in nInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        return ip.Address;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could instead explicitly ignore some network types:

```cs
        // Using a switch statement to make it a litte easier to change the logic
        switch (nInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)
        {
            case NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback:
                // ignore this type
                break;
            // Anything else that's running is considered valid
            default:
                foreach (var ip in nInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        return ip.Address;
                break;
        }
```