# How do I get the native IP in an Xamarin.MAC program

Tags: c#, xamarin

Now we have an Xamarin.mac GUI program that needs to get the native IP.
I use the following code:

Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.First(x=>x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

it works on my machine, but get error like "Could not resolve host '...'" on some others.

How can I avoid this error to get the IP ?

Comment: Why are you using DNS to find the IP of the machine?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814027