# How can I get the IP address from the user client in C#?

Tags: c#, logging, client, ip

I'm using this code that I found in [Get public IP using DynDNS and WebRequest C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597655/get-public-ip-using-dyndns-and-webrequest-c-sharp)

to get the IP address.  But I just get the IP Address from the server and what I need is the IP address from the user that is connected to my web application.

```
String direction = "";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
}

//Search for the ip in the html
int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);
```

Comment: What kind of code is this? If it's an ASP.NET application, then the client's IP address is already available in `Request.UserHostAddress`

Comment: This code will give you the public IP of the computer **running** the code, the code I've given below will give you the IP of the computer **requesting** your asp.net page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a web app, and you want your "client's" IP, [you need to use the UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx).

```
var userAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

First obtain a context:

```
HttpListenerContext ctx = m_HttpListener.GetContext();
```

After accepting the requset, client information is availble in `ctx`. Use `ctx` to get client IP addresss:

```
string IP = ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
```