# Get ip address using hostname on the network asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis

I have deployed an application on the IIS server, as per my requirement i need to get IP-Address of hosted machine which is on the network and i have just host-name of the machine using c#
e.g

```
http://abc
```

Where abc is deployed on IIS which can be any where on the network i don't know.
Is it possible to get IP-Address using this host-name with c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include

```
using System.Net;
```

and use

```
string url = "www.howtogeek.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(url);
```

The following answer also might be helpfule

> [How to get my own IP address in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

Comment: this s not live ipAddress it is on domain network please look at my example http://192.168.3.183/ApplicationName where 192.168.3.183 is unknown