# How to send the ping argument in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my own IP address in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

In C# console application, I am using this code

```
var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send();
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pinging with server");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

So in `var reply = ping.Send();` what argument do I need to pass so as it should write the IP of the local machine? Here I need IP of the local machine in the argument.

Comment: Please [see the documentation first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx). If there are any *remaining* questions not answered in the API documentation, then feel free to ask them. In addition, see this [How to: Ping a Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229713.aspx).

Comment: Here is how you can get your _local_ IP address : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Comment: Send doesn't "Write the ip of the local machine"--by "write the ip" I assume write tot he console...  If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: Just `Console.WriteLine("172.0.0.1");` and you have written your local IP address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does that:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var ping = new Ping())
            { 
                var reply = ping.Send(IPAddress.Loopback);

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pinging with server: " + reply.Address);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in following way:

```
 IPAddress add = IPAddress.Loopback; /// Reuturns local Ip Address
 PingReply reply = ping.Send(add);
 if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Pinging with server");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
```