# How can we know our own external ip address on the client

Tags: ip, ip-address

How can we know our own EXTERNAL IP address on the CLIENT (=our computer); NOT our internal IP address, NOT through an existing web site, NOT through a new website we would fabricate for this question; JUST with pure client OS commands scripting and/or JavaScript? Is that possible? In fact, if someone as a way to do that they should collect 1 million dollars because nobody has EVER come up with an answer to that on ANY website on this planet to my knowledge, A.R.

Comment: OK, C# (or Java, etc.) could also be used as per the question, although IF it's possible it would give a more complicated answer. A.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somebody DID [ask that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c), but using C#

```
IPHostEntry host;
string localIP = "?";
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        localIP = ip.ToString();
    }
}
return localIP;
```

I don't know the OS you're targeting, but you might create an console application and read the value from it

Hope it helps

Comment: I will try that and, if not satisfactory, take a look at the other question you're pointing at, thanks many. A.R.

Answer (score 1):

As Gricha mentioned, it can be requested via external site.  There is an open source project that is also hosted.

You can get your external IP info in JSON format by calling this API:

```
curl http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON
```

in C#, there must be a similar method to call web API.

The project info is here: http://code.google.com/p/ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an external ip address from a simple system call. You can receive it from the router, which is probably router specific, or you need to make a call from an something out side of your lan. Typically this is done through a HTTP request or some other popular internet service.

Also, individual computers on a local network don't have an external ip. The router has one address and forwards packets to the individual device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately you won't get the million bucks with that... Also, can we say that IF that does not exist, it SHOULD (in this dire information age)...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without going out of your current network.

To know your IP address you need to ask your router about. It's your router that gives you the IP in his network.

To know the IP address that belongs to your router in their network - you need to ask someone in that network about your IP. Because that network gives him an IP.

Finally if you want to know your IP outside your ISP's network - you need to ask someone *outside* your ISP's network about it.

Comment: I did NOT pose as a condition that you could not access a network to get it, only that you could not do it through outside means... Mostly informative but thanks anyway, A.R.