# Client' country name not returns correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address, whois

I am using the http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/ dll library for retrieving client's country and I am using the following code. But the result always show "Australia" but I am from Bangladesh. Can anybody correct me using that code?

```
using System.Net;
using WorldDomination.Net;

string userHostIpAddress = "203.1.2.3";
IPAddress ipAddress;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(userHostIpAddress, out ipAddress))
{
    string country = ipAddress.Country(); // return value: UNITED STATES
    string iso3166TwoLetterCode = ipAddress.Iso3166TwoLetterCode(); // return value: US
}
```

Comment: The ip address 203.1.2.3 is in Australia. Check this:http://www.ipaddresslabs.com/IPGeolocationServiceDemo.do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sample source code, in which the IP address is specified as a constant. It does not look up your own IP address!

```
string userHostIpAddress = "203.1.2.3"; // this is an Australian IP
```

You need to find your own IP and use *that*.

For example, this is explained in [How to get the IP address of the server on which my C# application is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

Comment: I can get public ip address only in a line: string ipAddress = new WebClient().DownloadString("icanhazip.com"); But when I send that as a parameter to userHostIpAddress I get null value as country name. I also try to assign my public ip directly to it and I get my correct country. What kind of problem is that?