# Local/Remote TCP info from process

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcp

I want to get the local ip:port and remote ip:port info of process by using VB.Net with oout any additional library.
Any Ideas how I can do it?
I am new in VB, sorry if question is dummy.

Comment: What do you mean with 'remote ip'? The ip address on the internet (before NAT etc.)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Comment: Yes, The ip address on the internet

Comment: @Roman in the internet there is an incrdible amount of agents with different ip's. Which one you want to know?

Comment: At my computer are set of processes I what to know local ip:port and remote ip:port info of process which I select from this set.

Comment: A process as in a running application? It sounds like you're looking for IP End point data from a TCP connection. Does tihs help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx