# Application Logs | IP Address + Pointer Issues

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, marshalling

I am very new to C++-CLI and recently finished working on my first "official" application. I was advised to create application logs to track its effectiveness. When the form opens, the application tracks the date, time, and PC username and writes it to a text file.

That works well, though I am having trouble displaying an IP Address. I receive an error "Type name is not allowed" on (System::Net::IPAddress).

```
            lastlineoffile += ( std::string((char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(DateTime::Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy")).ToPointer()) + "  "  + 
            std::string((char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(DateTime::Now.ToString("HH:mm")).ToPointer()) + "  " +
            //std::string((char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(System::Net::IPAddress).ToPointer()) + "  " +
            std::string((char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(System::Environment::UserName).ToPointer()) );
        std::cout << "last line to be added: " << lastlineoffile << std::endl;

        file << lastlineoffile.c_str();
        //saves usage text file
        file.close();
```

Additionally, I would like to record the time the application is exited. The previous perimeters are all recorded at the start of the application. I figure there would have to be a pointer that references the time off when the application closes. Any insight on how this would be accomplished would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System::Net::IPAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is the name of a class, not an object. It's a data storage class used for storing IP addresses. It's not an object you can pass to `StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

I'm guessing that you want to log your machine's IP address. OK, but which one? The computer I'm on right now has 6 of them, and would have more if I connected to a VPN. I'd follow the instructions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069103/480937) & [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069113/480937) to iterate over the IP addresses, and pick one, but you'll still have multiple if you have multiple network cards, whether real or virtual.

If all you need is a lightweight 'which machine is this' identifier, you may want to use [`Environment::MachineName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). That will give you the current machine's name, as a string.

Other notes:

- Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

  - Related to that, if you're writing C++/CLI, I would prefer to use the higher-level language when you have a choice. Therefore, I would favor the .Net File I/O, rather than unmanaged io streams. You're already writing managed code, with a very full-featured standard library, you might as well use it!
- `StringToHGlobalAnsi` is not the preferred way to convert from managed to unmanged strings. If you do want to use it, that's fine, but each call without a corresponding call to [`FreeHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is a memory leak. The preferred way is to use `marshal_as`, as described in [Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp). With `marshal_as`, you can convert directly from `String^` to `std::string`, and both classes manage their memory appropriately, so no memory leaks. (But using the higher-level language, and doing your logging with .Net classes, would be even better.)