# This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type 'string'

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I was attempting to convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-server-on-which-my-c-sharp-application-is-runni) to F# but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong as the error message (in title) is too broad of an error to search for, so I found no resolutions.

Here is the code:

```
let getIP : string =
    let host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    for ip in host.AddressList do
        if ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork then
            ip.ToString() // big fat red underline here
"?"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `for` loop in F# is for running imperative-style code, where the code inside the `for` loop does not produce a result but instead runs some kind of side-effect. Therefore, the expression block in an F# `for` loop is expected to produce the type `unit`, which is what side-effect functions should return. (E.g., `printfn "Something"` returns the `unit` type). Also, there's no way to exit a `for` loop early in F#; this is by design, and is another reason why a `for` loop isn't the best approach to do what you're trying to do.

What you're trying to do is go through a list one item at a time, find the *first* item that matches some condition, and return that item (and, if the item is not found, return some default value). F# has a specialized function for that: [`Seq.find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.find%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) (or `List.find` if `host.AddressList` is an F# list, or `Array.find` if `host.AddressList` is an array. Those three functions take different input types but all work the same way conceptually, so from now on I'll focus on `Seq.find`, which takes any `IEnumerable` as input so is most likely to be what you need here).

If you look at the `Seq.find` function's type signature in the F# docs, you'll see that it is:

```
('T -> bool) -> seq<'T> -> 'T
```

This means that the function takes two parameters, a `'T -> bool` and `seq<'T>` and returns a `'T`. The `'T` syntax means "this is a generic type called T": in F#, the apostrophe means that what follows is the name of a generic type. The type `'T -> bool` means a function that takes a `'T` and returns a Boolean; i.e., a predicate that says "Yes, this matches what I'm looking for" or "No, keep looking". The second argument to `Seq.find` is a `seq<'T>`; `seq` is F#'s shorter name for an `IEnumerable`, so you can read this as `IEnumerable<'T>`. And the result is an item of type `'T`.

Just from that function signature and name alone, you can guess what this does: it goes through the sequence of items and calls the predicate for each one; the first item for which the predicate returns true will be returned as the result of `Seq.find`.

But wait! What if the item you're looking for isn't in the sequence at all? Then `Seq.find` will throw an exception, which may not be the behavior you're looking for. Which is why the [`Seq.tryFind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.tryfind%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) function exists: its function signature looks just like `Seq.find`, except for the return value: it returns `'T option` rather than `'T`. That means that you'll either get a result like `Some "ip address"` or `None`. In your case, you intend to return `"?"` if the item isn't found. So you want to convert a value that's either `Some "ip address` or `None` to either `"ip address"` (without the `Some`) or `"?"`. That is what the [`defaultArg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.defaultarg%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function is for: it takes a `'T option`, and a `'T` representing the default value to return if your value is `None`, and it returns a plain `'T`.

So to sum up:

- `Seq.tryFind` takes a predicate function and a sequence, and returns a `'T option`. In your case, this will be a `string option`
- `defaultArg` takes a `'T option` and a default value, and returns a normal `'T` (in your case, a `string`).

With these two pieces, plus a predicate function you can write yourself, we can do what you're looking for.

One more note before I show you the code: you wrote `let getIP : string = (code)`. It seems like you intended for `getIP` to be a function, but you didn't give it any parameters. Writing `let something = (code block)` will create a *value* by running the code block immediately (and just once) and then assigning its result to the name `something`. Whereas writing `let something() = (code block)` will create a *function*. It will not run the code block immediately, but it will instead run the code block every time the function is called. So I think you should have written `let getIP() : string = (code)`.

Okay, so having explained all that, let's put this together to give you a `getIP` function that actually works:

```
let getIP() =  // No need to declare the return type, since F# can infer it
    let isInternet ip =  // This is the predicate function
        // Note that this function isn't accessible outside of getIP()
        ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork
    let host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    let maybeIP = Seq.tryFind isInternet host.AddressList
    defaultArg maybeIP "?"
```

I hope that's clear enough; if there's anything you don't understand, let me know and I'll try to explain further.

**Edit:** The above has one possible flaw: the fact that F# may not be able to infer the type of the `ip` argument in `isInternet` without an explicit type declaration. It's clear from the code that it needs to be *some* class with an `.AddressFamily` property, but the F# compiler can't know (at this point in the code) *which* class you intend to pass to this predicate function. That's because the F# compiler is a **single-pass** compiler, that works its way through the code in a top-down, left-to-right order. To be able to infer the type of the `ip` parameter, you might need to rearrange the code a little, as follows:

```
let getIP() =  // No need to declare the return type, since F# can infer it
    let host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    let maybeIP = host.AddressList |> Seq.tryFind (fun ip -> ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    defaultArg maybeIP "?"
```

This is actually more idiomatic F# anyway. When you have a predicate function being passed to `Seq.tryFind` or other similar functions, the most common style in F# is to declare that predicate as an anonymous function using the `fun` keyword; this works just like lambdas in C# (in C# that predicate would be `ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork`). And the other thing that's common is to use the `|>` operator with things like `Seq.tryFind` and others that take predicates. The `|>` operator basically* takes the value that's before the `|>` operator and passes it as the **last** parameter of the function that's after the operator. So `foo |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> xyz)` is just like writing `Seq.tryFind (fun x -> xyz) foo`, except that `foo` is the first thing you read in that line. And since `foo` is the sequence that you're looking in, and `fun x -> xyz` is *how* you're looking, that feels more natural: in English, you'd say "Please look in my closet for a green shirt", so the concept "closet" comes up before "green shirt". And in idiomatic F#, you'd write `closet |> Seq.find (fun shirt -> shirt.Color = "green")`: again, the concept "closet" comes up before "green shirt".

With this version of the function, F# will encounter `host.AddressList` before it encounters `fun ip -> ...`, so it will know that the name `ip` refers to one item in `host.AddressList`. And since it knows the type of `host.AddressList`, it will be able to infer the type of `ip`.

* There's a lot more going on behind the scenes with the `|>` operator, involving [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/) and [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/). But at a beginner level, just think of it as "puts a value at the end of a function's parameter list" and you'll have the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

In F# any if/else/then-statement must evaluate to the same type of value for all branches. Since you've omitted the else-branch of the expression, the compiler will infer it to return a value of type unit, effectively turning your if-expression into this:

```
if ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork then
    ip.ToString() // value of type string
else
    () // value of type unit
```

Scott Wlaschin explains this better than me on the excellent [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/control-flow-expressions/#how-to-use-if-then-else).

This should fix the current error, but still won't compile. You can solve this either by translating the C#-code more directly (using a mutable variable for the localIP value, and doing `localIP <- ip.ToString()` in your if-clause, or you could look into a more idiomatic approach using something like [Seq.tryFind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.tryfind%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: That's actually more correct than what I said about `for` loops expecting values of type `unit`. If the original code had included `else "?"` then F# would have emitted a warning "The result of this expression has type 'string' and is implicitly ignored" but allowed it to compile. (It still wouldn't have given the right result, though).