# Is it possible to get the mac address using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Was wondering if it was possible to get the mac address of the server using a stored procedure?
I did some searching for a while but found nothing. This is using SQL2008.

**Update**
Unfortunately the answer that uses newsequentialid() can return the wrong
MacAddress if there is VMWare on the server.

Comment: What should happen if there are two network cards?

Comment: I'm just going to grab all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you'd need to execute a shell command from SQL to get the MAC address. If I recall correctly, you have to turn on the execute shell command option before you can use it. Then, you could run "getmac" to retrieve a list of MAC address for the interfaces on the server. You'd have to work your way through the text returned, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat round about method!

```
declare @t table
(
i uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),
m as cast(i as char(36))
)

insert into @t default values;

select
    substring(m,25,2) + '-' + 
    substring(m,27,2) + '-' + 
    substring(m,29,2) + '-' +
    substring(m,31,2) + '-' +
    substring(m,33,2) + '-' +
    substring(m,35,2) AS MacAddress
FROM @t
```

Comment: <strike>It works like a charm but I still don't understand how its getting it.</strike> I get it, newsequentialid uses mac addresses. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately newsequentialid() can return the wrong MacAddress if there is VMWare on the server.

Comment: @Donny - Ah to be honest I felt a bit uncomfortable relying on that anyway. I guess the algorithm could change without warning at some point in the future.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I followd you query but yesterday it was giving me the value "85-61-27-27-FF-A7" and now when i checkd it, it generates "B8-CA-3A-D0-2C-6F". What is the problem? Is there anything that can be persistent throughout?

Answer (score 1):

[sys.sysprocesses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx), net_address column. For my connection from SSMS it's `795C70BAD9B0`

There is no equivalent in sys.dm_exec_connections  (net_address is IP address not MAC address and is [111.222.111.222](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) from my SSMS). In fact there is no [sys.sysprocesses equivalent either](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/257502/deprecation-of-sysprocesses-dmvs-doesnt-fully-replace-all-columns)

So you can just query sys.sysprocesses in your own stored proc...

Comment: But that's the address of a client connecting to the server, which is not necessarily connecting from the same machine. As far as I can see, internal system processes don't have that column filled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since in Sql Server 2008, a Stored proc can contained managed code, it should be possible, however, you'd technically be running a c#/vb app which was launched by SqlServer, rather than truly getting the info from a stored proc, although that more of a theoric rather than practical difference.

Comment: Managed procedures *are* stored procedures, the term technically covers both T-SQL and CLR. And there is no 'app launched by SQL Server' either, SQL Server *is* a CLR host itself, it does not launch apps to run managed code.

Comment: Granted I phrased that badly.  how 'bout "SQL doesn't enter into this solution, so it's not really a stored proc in the conventional sense, but it's run like one"

Comment: Actually this doesn't work because you need to creat a SQLServerProject to deploy and debug CLR stored procedures.
SQLServerProject doesn't support System.Managment.

Comment: You don't need System.Management.  You want System.Net.NetworkInformation, which is available.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151231/how-do-i-get-the-local-network-ip-address-of-a-computer-programmatically-c  (Skipped the accepted answer and read the next one or mine further down)

Comment: I'm looking at the available references and I'm not seeing System.NET.

Comment: @Donny: System.Net.NetworkInformation is a namespace, not an assembly.  It is contained in the System.dll assembly.

Answer (score 0):

> declare @macadd nvarchar(50)   select @macadd=net_address
>       from master.dbo.sysprocesses
>       where program_name like 'SQLAgent%' and hostname=SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') and net_address<>'000000000000'
>   --getting the MAC address    set @macadd=SUBSTRING(@macadd,1,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@macadd,3,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@macadd,5,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@macadd,7,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@macadd,9,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@macadd,11,2)
>   --To include '-' between each two characters of MAC address   select @macadd

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IP_Address varchar(20);
DECLARE @mac_Address varchar(20);

SELECT @IP_Address=client_net_address,@mac_Address=net_address 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
    join sys.sysprocesses p on c.session_id=p.spid
    WHERE c.Session_id = @@SPID
```

Comment: it's exactly as:
select net_address from sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID .
This won't give the MAC address but some other net address (I checked)