# SQL Server : does NEWID() always gives a unique ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, unique, newid

Does the `NEWID()` function never give me the same ID as it already did? Let's say I select a `NEWID()` and it returns '1' (just as an example). Will it never return '1' again? Is it impossible?

Comment: if it does, run out and buy a lottery ticket.

Comment: It's not impossible, but _highly_ unlikely.

Comment: The probability is so low, that for all intents and purposes it is impossible.

Comment: It is not *impossible*, because `NEWID()` is based on a pseudorandom number (plus the MAC address of the computer on which is is generated), so yes, it *could* happen. But it almost certainly won't.

Comment: Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550346/how-sql-server-creates-uniqueidentifier-using-newid

Answer (score 32):

Both [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) and [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) give globally unique values of type [`uniqueidentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql).

`NEWID()` involves random activity, thus the next value is unpredictable, and it's slower to execute.

`NEWSEQUENTIALID()` doesn't involve random activity, thus [the next generated value can be predicted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158118/1429387) (not easily!) and executes faster than `NEWID()`.

So, if you're not concerned about the next value being predicted (for security reasons), you can use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. If you're concerned about predictability or you don't mind the tiny performance penalty you can use `NEWID()`.

However, in strict sense, there are still negligible chances that GUIDs generated by different machines have the same value. In practice, it's considered as being impossible.

If you want further info, read this: [Which method for generating GUIDs is best for ensuring the GUID is really unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472251/which-method-for-generating-guids-is-best-for-ensuring-the-guid-is-really-uniqu)

Note `NEWID()` complies [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). And the other function uses a Microsoft's algorithm for generating the value.

Answer (score 12):

If you're running `NEWID()` on the same machine then the return value will always be unique because it incorporates the current time stamp in its calculation.

On separate machines/systems, however, you could *technically* get the same id but the probability of that happening is so low that today's SQL DB community has essentially accepted that it IS impossible. Microsoft has more or less banked their reputation on it.

Related

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550377/1439748
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: what about asynchronous operations which has same timestamp ?

Comment: ok, i tried some little tests and it seems ok, records with same timestamp has different newid on the same machine.. its probably due to random part of that function.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, so I ran this simple query to see how unique the newid () could be, as you'll see there is no repeated IDs even in the same milisecond:

```
DECLARE @TRIES BIGINT, @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @REPEATED_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @TRIES = 1
SET @REPEATED_ID=NEWID()
WHILE @TRIES <= 1000
BEGIN
    SET @ID=NEWID() 
    IF @REPEATED_ID=@ID
        PRINT 'SAME -> ID '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@TRIES)+': '+ CONVERT(CHAR(36),@ID)
    ELSE
        PRINT 'DISTINCT -> ID '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@TRIES)+': '+ CONVERT(CHAR(36),@ID) + ' AT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2(3)) 
)
    SET @TRIES += 1
    SET @REPEATED_ID=@ID
END
```

You can define @TRIES as you wish.

Comment: That proves little, because 1) T-SQL's interpreter is pretty slow and 2) not getting the same IDs in the same millisecond does not prove that, say, the values wouldn't be recycled next day, or next month, or next year. GUIDs *are* unique, but establishing that empirically isn't practical.

Comment: exactly, but this is only a guide. All depends that you want to do and for what do you need this IDs.