# How to generate a Guid in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql

I need to create an Id as Guid in SQL(no identity) How I can do this? I defined the Id as uniqueidentifier but what is save in Db is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908776/sql-server-does-newid-always-gives-a-unique-id

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Use [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate a Guid in SQL Server like this:

```sql
SELECT NEWID()

-- Creating a local variable with DECLARE/SET syntax.  
DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier  
SET @myid = NEWID()  
PRINT 'Value of @myid is: '+ CONVERT(varchar(255), @myid)  
-- Value of @myid is: 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF
```

According to the [NEWID() msft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> NEWID() is compliant with RFC4122.

FROM THE [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) abstract

> This specification defines a Uniform Resource Name namespace for
> UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally
> Unique IDentifier).  A UUID is 128 bits long, and can guarantee
> uniqueness across space and time.

Answer (score 12):

Create a variable of uniqueidentifier data type.
Type the below code in SSMS and execute.

```
 DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
 SELECT @guid as 'GUID';
```

Here we created a variable named guid of data type uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 8):

A aspnet role created manually

```
DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @ID = NEWID()

DECLARE @STAMP UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @STAMP = NEWID()

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
           ([Id]
           ,[Name]
           ,[NormalizedName]
           ,[ConcurrencyStamp])
     VALUES
           (@ID
           ,'Admin'
           ,'ADMIN'
           ,@STAMP)
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a GUID in SQL Server, use the `NEWID()` function. It produces a globally unique alphanumeric value of 128 bits, ideal for primary keys or unique identifiers in databases.

SELECT NEWID() AS GeneratedGUID;