# Azure Active Directory Object ID data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory

Which data type in SQL Server is the correct one for object id in Azure Active Directory?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU8jy.png)

Comment: Looks like a Guid - so I'd pick a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in SQL Server ......

Answer (score 0):

The object id is look like GUID format (**Globally Unique Identifier**) this GUID is based on machine information in sql server GUID is known by `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type

So as mentioned by [**marc**](https://user:13302) you can use `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type in SQL Server is the correct one for object id in Azure Active Directory

> your object id is a base 16-byte number that **4**91a that four is
> basically represent what version you are using and yours's Random ID
> version its claim to uniqueness, if you have two same random id
> (object id) chances of having collision and it incredibly low so make
> sure while choosing recheck object id's

Please check this [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250180/how-to-generate-a-guid-in-sql-server) by *Manish Kumar Gurjar* which worked on the similar thread

To more in detail please **refer** this link :

[Understanding the GUID data type in SQL Server by  [Ben Richardson](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-guid-data-type-in-sql-server/)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Hey, did the suggestion work? do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.  [Help Center -SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)