# What is the best way to avoid duplication of data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code below to `generate series number` upon saving of the user. But my problem is if the user of the system save at the same time`(many user)` it has a possibility to have a duplicate series number.

```
  public string GenerateSeriesNumber(string code, Entities db, string Ctrl)
    {
        string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2);

        string prev_ctrls = "";
        var tbl = db.SeriesTable.Where(a => a.SeriesNo.Contains(Ctrl)).OrderByDescending(a => a.SeriesNo);
        foreach (var item in tbl.ToList())
        {
            string[] current_srs = item.SeriesNo.Split('-');
            if (prev_srs == "")
                prev_srs = item.SeriesNo;

            int aaa = Convert.ToInt32(prev_srs.Split('-')[3]);
            int bbb = Convert.ToInt32(current_srs[3]);
            if (aaa < bbb)
                prev_srs = item.SeriesNo;

        }
        string Series_No = "";

        if (tbl != null)
        {
            string[] LastSeries_No = prev_srs.Split('-');
            if (LastSeries_No.Length == 4)
            {
                LastSeries_No[3] = Int32.Parse(LastSeries_No[3]) + 1 + "";
                for (int i = LastSeries_No[3].Length; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    LastSeries_No[3] = "0" + LastSeries_No[3];
                }
                LastSeries_No[1] = code.ToUpper();
                Series_No = String.Join("-", LastSeries_No);
                return Series_No;
            }
        }
       
        return Series_No;
    }
```

I tried to execute this in my SQL `(I am using SQL Server 2017)` but one of them encountered an error and didn't save

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SeriesTable
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_LT UNIQUE (SeriesNo);
```

Comment: One option would be to create a unique index and when an exception is thrown just generate another number.

Comment: @user743414 I have tried it, when it encounter an error. Upon return to my Javascript I call again the function to save. But unfortunately one of them encountered an error as stated above.

Comment: You probably already have duplicate data in your table - you should solve the duplicate rows and recreate the constraint or add a WITH NOCHECK . you could add a new_id() to the end of the key if the length is not a issue

Comment: @Mitz sorry for the late response. the only time that will encounter a duplicate data if they save the data at the same time. as mention above

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplication of data, you can use different methods:

- Identity columns (not best for serial keys)
- NEWID() - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908776/sql-server-does-newid-always-gives-a-unique-id)
- a Sequence

In your case i'd use NEWID(), or just a sequence number and add dashes('-') between digits.

p.s. If there are other requirements that force you to make the serial number incremental or meaningful in some way, you should have included them in the question.