# What argument should I pass to get my workstation ip in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my own IP address in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

In console application I need to pass the ip of my machine so what argument do I need to pass?

```
var myIp = Convert.ToString("");

if (search = value1.Contains(myIp))
{
    foo..
    foo..
}
```

So what argument should I send like I am using `IPAddress` but is not giving my ip?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I find the ip of my machine?"

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do exactly? Can you show the code with the IPAddress?

Comment: yes the ip of my machine just from system.networkinfomation we have parameters right??

Comment: Yes. Actually, system.networkinformation is even better. There's a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151231/how-do-i-get-the-local-network-ip-address-of-a-computer-programmatically-c

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the IP (IPv4) addresses of your machine (you may have more than one):

```
var myAddresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
                     .AddressList
                     .Where(e => e.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Dns.GetHostEntry() as this goes is a DNS network call, and it may fail under some circumstances. If it were me, I wouldn't query through the DNS system I'd just use WMI to read the data on the local hardware. Here's a post that does this;

http://kodefumaster.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/getting-the-network-adaptor-mac-ip-address-with-wmi/

Remember that each network card might have multiple IP addresses as well.

[Updated]

...or even easier, System.Net.NetworkInformation as you've already noted in your comments. See here;

[How do I get the Local Network IP address of a computer programmatically? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151231/how-do-i-get-the-local-network-ip-address-of-a-computer-programmatically-c)

But I wouldn't use DNS unless you specifically want to.