# How do I get the local host IP address in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, ip, windows-store-apps

A particular rest service I am calling in a Windows Store app wants the IP address of the calling computer as a parameter. None of the tried and true examples using [System.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151231/how-do-i-get-the-local-network-ip-address-of-a-computer-programmatically-c) or [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vblanguage/thread/EDA3FE2B-28D5-4C13-A333-DB0AD76F52EA) compile in a Store app.

What is the magical combination of types and methods available in a windows store app that will get to the local machine's IP address? I feel like it is probably obvious but I am not seeing it!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to contact an external server. Even if the platform supplies an API to retrieve the network address, the host could still be located behind a proxy or a NAT (and you will see something like 192.168.1.4, instead of your external IP address).

Just perform an HTTP request towards services like http://ifconfig.me/ or http://whatismyip.com/ and parse the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Local network IP address:

```
foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
{
    if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
    {
        if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
        {
            // E.g.: 192.168.1.108
            Debug.WriteLine(localHostName);
        }
    }
}
```