# Get the list of connected machines IP address of lan for Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, networking, windows-store-apps

Actually I tried to get the list of Ip Addresses of the LAN for Windows Store
Apps using Xaml and C#. Can Any one Please tell me how to do this and  referred this link [How to get LocalNetwork IP Address For WindowsStore Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018978/how-to-get-localnetwork-ip-address-for-windowsstore-apps) but it is showing the local machine Ip address but I want the list of connected host names and Ip addresses which are connected to the local server in LAN. Here is my code:

```
var hostNamesList = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation
        .GetHostNames();

            foreach (var entry in hostNamesList)
            {
                if (entry.Type == Windows.Networking.HostNameType.DomainName)
                {


                    var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

                    if (icp != null && icp.NetworkAdapter != null)
                    {
                        var hostname =
                            NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().SingleOrDefault(
                                hn =>
                                hn.IPInformation != null &&
                                hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId ==
                                icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);


                        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(hostname.CanonicalName);
                        await msg.ShowAsync();
                        MessageDialog msg1 = new MessageDialog(entry.RawName);
                        await msg1.ShowAsync();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Based on the link that you have posted there ..what is your HostName that you are passing.. ? can you provide some code that you have that shows how you are actually trying to get the list of ip addresses on the lan..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - I have just added a code in my question. Please refer that and advise me

Comment: Baskar, I have just tested this on my local laptop and I have another laptop which runs Ubuntu and I was able to return the ip address of that machine based on the passing the name of the Machine on my network at home I don't have windows 8 but I am wondering if this same thing would work for you