# How can I programatically get the IP address of a peer in an adhoc network?

Tags: windows, winapi, ip, adhoc

I have developed a program in an academic project. This program includes a client and a server portion and aims to allow two notebooks to exchange information in an adhoc network:

1. The program should establish an adhoc connection with another computer
2. The program should send a message to the other computer through the adhoc connection

I did the first step. I developed a program that uses Windows WLAN API to connect to an adhoc network. The problem is the second step. I want to use Sockets API to send the message. Therefore, I need the IP address of the other computer. How can I get the IP address of this computer in an adhoc network?

Comment: Show the relevant portions of the code you've already written.

Comment: Basically, you have to [scan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151237/612717).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to enumerate all the network interfaces connected to your network and dump the addresses known for each adapter. Something like this:

```
var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()))
                    .AddressList
                    .Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    .Select(ip => ip.ToString())
                    .ToArray();
```

Also take a look at [ManagedWifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)